# Create a data frame with unique combo generated from nested for loops

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, nested, anova

I have a data frame as such:

```
  Feature ID Sub Value
1       A T1  B1  5.87
2       B T1  B2  3.99
3       C T1  B3 12.57
4       A T1  B2  9.22
5       B T1  B3  7.89
6       C T1  B1  4.76
7       A T2  B1  4.56
8       B T2  B2  9.26
9       C T2  B2  7.44
```

What I want to do is run one factor ANOVA in this dataset with the factor being "Sub". I want to loop through each feature and loop through each ID. Basically, I am calculating the variance of each feature within an ID, between "Sub".

I have generated the below code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
datalist <- list()

for (i in unique(data1$Feature)) {
  for (j in unique(data1$ID)) {
    A1 <- summary(aov(data1$value ~ as.factor(data1$Sub), data=data1))
    datalist[[j]] <- A1
  }
}

big_data <- do.call(rbind, datalist)
```

I end up getting big_data which is a matrix of 36 lists. I am unable to access the Anova output. It doesn't have to necessarily be a data frame. Even if it's a "write.csv()" within the loop that will generate the different outputs. Ultimately, I'll just be needing the "between" factor parameter of the Anova output to generate a plot so if this can also be incorporated in the code that'd be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues with current setup:

- You do not actually use `i` and `j` in your `anova` call, so all nested `for` loop iterations will return exact same results run on entire data frame. Quick Fix: `subset` data frame by i-th and j-th values.

  ```r
  anova(value ~ Sub, data = subset(data1, Feature == i & ID == j))
  ```
- You save list elements only under `j` values and not both `i` and `j`, so iterations will reassign repeatedly and only saves *last* pass of `j` items. Quick fix: add named elements of i-th and j-th values.

  ```r
  datalist[[paste0(i, "_", j)]] <- A1
  ```
- You are attempting to `rbind` list objects, not matrices or data frames, since `summary.anova` returns a list of results. For your use case, calling `str` shows your results contain a list of 1:

  ```r
  str(summary(aov(data1$value ~ as.factor(data1$Sub), data = data1)))
  List of 1
  $ :Classes ‘anova’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  5 variables:
    ..$ Df     : num [1:2] ...
    ..$ Sum Sq : num [1:2] ...
    ..$ Mean Sq: num [1:2] ...
    ..$ F value: num [1:2] ...
    ..$ Pr(>F) : num [1:2] ...
  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "summary.aov" "listof"
  ```

  Quick fix: index the first item.

  ```r
  summary(anova(...))[[1]]
  ```

---

However, consider an *apply* family solution with `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) and avoid the bookkeeping of initializing lists and assign iteratively in nested `for` loops. Specifically, `by` can split up data frame by one or more groups and run operations on the subsets to return a list equal to all possible unique values of groups. Also, consider using a defined method to encapsulate all processing on each subset.

```r
# USER-DEFINED METHOD
run_anova <- function(sub_df) {
  # RAW RESULTS
  anova_raw <- summary(aov(value ~ Sub, data = sub_df))[[1]]

  # CLEAN UP DATA WITH IDENTIFIERS
  anova_df <- data.frame(
    within(anova_raw, {Feature <- sub_df$Feature[1]; ID <- sub_df$ID[1]}),
    row.names = NULL,
    check.names = FALSE
  )
  
  return(anova_df)
}

datalist <- by(data1, data1[c("Feature", "ID")], run_anova)
  
big_data <- do.call(rbind, unname(datalist))
```